# Angular 2+ How to use an variable value to call a directive?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using material angular, and the regular button is

`<button mat-button> x </button> or 
<button mat-raised-button> x </button>`

I have a string variable, lets call it 'type', and it's value can be 'mat-button' or 'mat-raised-button', can i call the 'directive' of the button using this variable? something like:

```
<button [type]> x </button>
```

This case above is more like an example of what i'm trying to do, but to make it simple, the question is how to 'use' a directive using a variable value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<button mat-button>` and `<button mat-raised-button>` are actually the same component with just different CSS styles applied.

You can just change the CSS style manually to alter the look of the button.

```
<button mat-button [class.mat-button]="!raised" [class.mat-raised-button]="raised">Hello World</button>
```

**Updated:**

```
<button mat-button [class]="type">Hello World</button>
```

Where the value of type can be a string `mat-button` or `mat-raised-button`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but like i said in the last answer, the case in the question is an example, i need a way to deal with it on other situations too, if possible with a way to put the variable value directly on the component

Comment: Well, this again will work only in this case, and not on a case where the variable should trigger a directive for example. But it worked and helped me in this case, so i'm marking this as the correct answer

Comment: Just a word of caution about using `[class]="type"` binding - that works okay here, but doing this generally will remove any classes already applied and replace the entire class list with the value of the bound variable. It would be better to use `[ngClass]="type"`to avoid that and merely add the class value to the class list.

Comment: @G.Tranter that was my intention here. The `mat-button` directive applies CSS styles, and then I need to replace it with the "type". But yeah, it's often a source of bugs when you don't know it works that way.

Answer (score 2):

you can use ngSwitch to create your template

```js
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="type">
  <ng-template [ngSwitchCase]= "'mat-button'">
    <button mat-button></button>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template [ngSwitchCase]= "'mat-raised-button'">
     <button mat-raised-button></button>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ngSwitchDefault> No Direction </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: It's a good answer, but i'm already doing that. I'm wanting to create some situations that will use a lot more options, and was looking for an easier approach